# Strange breakpoint behaviour (moving to a different location, and additional ones appearing)

Tags: javascript, developer-tools

When I am debugging with the Chrome Developer Tools, I often see that the breakpoints which I have just set, are being moved to a different location (usually a bit further down from their original location).
This location shift happens when I reload the page to start the debugging with these breakpoints.
It can be rather annoying, as you don't expect it to happen & a lot of the times you also do not see it happening. And then it leaves you wondering why certain breakpoints don't activate as you expect them to do...!
(I cannot provide you with a reproducible example - sorry)

Another behaviour that I see often, is when, after adding breakpoints & reloading, the devtools will halt at sort-of-random breakpoints which I have not set myself. These breakpoints seem to be exclusively happen/being set in imported/third-party code.
For example, before getting to any of my breakpoints, the devtools will halt somewhere in the source map of Vue, or the source map of a polyfills file that I have included.
I remove these breakpoints when they occur, but very often they come back again, although usually at slightly different locations (and again almost always in third-party & included  code).

Comment: Are you loading exactly the same script files every time, or does your server generate them dynamically?

Comment: I am modifying some files before I do the reload (with the strange behaviour), so not all of the files will be exactly the same.

The second behaviour (of breakpoints being added), happens always to files which I did not change. And which also the webpack (watch) process should not have changed upon reload.